# Request method 'POST' not supported with Spring

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

Excuse me for my english, it's not my language by default.

I use Spring and SpringSecurity in a project to build an API and I have an error since this morning.

My class to build the service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/object" })
public class ObjectApiController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public JsonResponse updateObject(@RequestBody BodyRequest bodyrequest) {
    // My code here
    }
```

My class BodyRequest:

```
public class BodyTpe {
    private String arg1=null;
    private String arg2=null;

    public String getArg1() {
        return arg1;
    }
    public void setArg1(String arg1) {
        this.arg1= arg1;
    }
    public String getArg2() {
        return arg2;
    }
    public void setArg2(String arg2) {
        this.arg2= arg2;
    }
```

And this is my request on Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'myaddress/api/object/update' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
--data-raw '{"arg1":"325-919-319",
"arg2":"116"}'
```

When I launch the request with postman, I have this error:

> Request method 'POST' not supported

Any idea why it's not working ?

Comment: A complete stacktrace related to this issue would be really helpful to analyse it. This issue can happen because of many reason, so a complete stacktrace is required

Comment: Is your configuration the scans package where your controller class is present?

Answer (score 0):

For post to work, you need to use csrf. So either supply a csrf via your form or disable it.

Comment: Thank you, I did this and it's ok now !

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@RequestMapping` annotation to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/object")
```